# Using String.Replace() with an index instead of a string for the argument?

Tags: c#

This seems like a simple problem but I'm not sure how to tackle it. I have a line of code that removes a part of a string. I simply want to change this from just removing to replacing it with something else. Is there a way I can use the string.replace with the index like I do in the following code sample?

```
output = output.Remove(m.Index, m.Length);
```

Comment: m is a regex match but it shouldn't be relevant to the issue, as in compile time it's just an integer.

Comment: @proseidon Why aren't you using `Regex.Replace` instead ?

Comment: You need to use substring http://www.dotnetperls.com/substring

Comment: @proseidon why not use regular expressions?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there's nothing to do this. The simplest approach would be to just use `Substring` and string concatenation:

```
public static string Replace(string text, int start, int count,
                             string replacement)
{
    return text.Substring(0, start) + replacement 
         + text.Substring(start + count);
}
```

Note that this ensures you definitely *won't* replace other sections of the string which also happen to match that text.

Answer (score 3):

All great answers, you can also do this:

```
  String result = someString.Remove(m.Index, m.Length).Insert(m.Index, "New String Value");
```

It's not the prettiest code but it works.

It will generally be better to write this into a extension method or some sort of base functionality so you don't have to repeat yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just do:

```
output = output.Replace(output.Substring(m.Index, m.Length), "Whatever I want to replace with");
```

NB: This will replace all instances of the substring.

Comment: That would work, but is inefficient. Since you know where the text to be replaced begins and ends, just replace that portion of the string rather than then searching for matching text.

Answer (score 0):

I am taking **replacing it with something else**, you may try this to replace it with other string:-

```
string s= original.Substring(0, start) + "ABCDEF"+ 
              original.Substring(end);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will remove a substring based on the index and length, and then replace it with the replacement string.

Jon's answer is, not surprisingly, more accurate, as it won't replace multiple instances of the removal string.

```
    static string Replace(string output, string replacement, int index, int length)
    {
        string removeString = output.Substring(index, length);
        return output.Replace(removeString, replacement);
    }
```